# How to setup ineractive-endpoint in RASA

Tags: python, python-3.x, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I am trying to deploy RASA chatbot on slack but I am facing an issue as shown in the picture below:[image: slack]

I am unable to understand what URL is it asking for.
In rasa endpoints.yml I have only action_endpoint as below :-

> action_endpoint:
>    url: "http://localhost:5055/webhook"

Now slack is not picking up the url.
So, please help me with what url I have to put here and where is that URL ?

I am new to RASA and Stack Overflow, so apologies if the question is low level.

Any help on this is appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to expose your local rasa server (not the action server) running at `localhost:5005` using [`ngrok`](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/messaging-and-voice-channels/#using-ngrok), then fill that spot with the URL of this type `http://<host>:<port>/webhooks/slack/webhook` as indicated in [the docs](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/connectors/slack/).